# Using Perl to replace empty string with space

Tags: perl

I have a bcp file that uses a field delimiter of `+*{tab}`.  So an empty column would have the previous tab and then `+*`.  I'm trying to use this to replace the empty value with a space using Perl for Windows

`perl -i -p -e "s/\t+*/\t +*/g" filename.bcp`

This is giving me Nested quantifiers in regex issue.

Comment: What shell are you using (Window's or bash?) If you're using bash, you should be using single quotes (for consistency if nothing else)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers (some of which you already have! :) ).

Answer (score 2):

`+` is a regex metacharacter. To specify a literal `+` character, you need to escape it

```
perl -i -p -e "s/\t\+/\t +/g" filename.bcp
```

or put it into a character class

```
perl -i -p -e "s/\t[+]/\t +/g" filename.bcp
```

Comment: So is `*` - I don't think that was intended to be a metacharacter either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mob.  I was able to get what I needed but using this:

perl -i -p -e "s/\t[+][*]/\t +*/g" filename.bcp